# how to find out number from given string using preg_match?

Tags: php, preg-match

```
if (
  preg_match("/^bundle id/", trim($rows[$key])) && 
  preg_match('/\d/', trim($rows[$key]), $temp))
```

.

```
bundle id 1 mode active
bundle id 99 mode active
bundle id 999 mode active
```

how to find out 1,99 and 999 in given preg_match expression.

Comment: Is your `bundle id` one line or many? For example multiple examples?

Answer (score 0):

Your second `preg_match` needs to become `preg_match_all`, and the regex needs to look for `\d+`, which is one or more numerical digits:

```
preg_match_all('/\d+/', trim($rows[$key]), $temp))
```

`$temp` will now contain an array of values:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '99' (length=2)
      2 => string '999' (length=3)
```

#### Edit

The above answer was on the basis that the sample string is one line.

If each line represents a different string, then all you need to do is alter the regex to`\d+`:

```
if(preg_match("/^bundle id/", trim($rows[$key])) && 
    preg_match('/\d+/', trim($rows[$key]), $temp))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

```
preg_match("/^bundle id\s*(\d+)/", trim($rows[$key]), $match)
```

Then the results are in `$match[1]`